# Why does %c format specifier not work in the following code?

Tags: c, printf, clang

I've just started reading about C and currently playing around with format specifiers.
Here is the code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    char code = 'a' - 'A';
    printf("\n>>>%c (%d)", code, code);
    printf("\n>>>%c", 32);

    char incode;
    printf("\n\nGive me some char: ");
    scanf("%c", &incode);
    printf("\n>>>%c (%d)", incode, incode);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
PS C:\ex> ./print

>>>  (32)
>>>

Give me some char: A

>>>A (65)
```

So, why does `%c` work in the last `printf` and doesn't work in the beginning?
I tested this sample on Windows and on Linux and both behave identically.

- Windows compiler: `gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`
- Linux compiler: `clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)`

Comment: Why do you believe the first `printf` did not work? What is your expected output?

Comment: Boths samples are working, `'a' - 'A'` returns 32 (the space character)  and thats what is printed.

Comment: What makes you think that it is not working? What did you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASCII 32 is `' '` (space).  It is printed alright, you just can't see it.
If you change the format string to `"\n>>>%c<< (%d)"` you will see it in the (pun) negative space.
You can also pass the output through `od -a` to confirm.

Comment: I like you answer. I just do not get the "negative space" thing. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  It was word play (pun) on the answer being "space" and the word also occurs in the art term "negative space" which wikipedia defines as "Negative space may be most evident when the space around a subject, not the subject itself, forms an interesting or artistically relevant shape," https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space

Comment: Interesting, thanks for clarfiying.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your character encoding is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Then `a` is encoded as 97 (decimal) and `A` is encoded as 65 (decimal). Their difference is 32, which encodes the   space character.

So `char code = 'a' - 'A';` is the same as `char code = 32;` which is the same as  the declaration `char code = ' ';`

See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

If allowed, compile with all warnings and debug info, so (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

You could compile your C source code `minerals.c` with `gcc -Wall -O -fverbose-asm minerals.c -S -o minerals.s` and look inside the generated assembler code `foo.s`. On my Debian computer with GCC 10.2 I am getting the following warning:

```
minerals.c: In function ‘main’:
minerals.c:11:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
   11 |     scanf("%c", &incode);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The generated assembler code has:

```
 # /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:107:   return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
         movl    $32, %ecx       #,
         movl    $32, %edx       #,
         leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi        #,
         movl    $1, %edi        #,
         call    __printf_chk@PLT        #
         movl    $32, %edx       #,           // 32 is the space
         leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rsi        #,
         movl    $1, %edi        #,
         movl    $0, %eax        #,
         call    __printf_chk@PLT        #
         leaq    .LC2(%rip), %rsi        #,
         movl    $1, %edi        #,
         movl    $0, %eax        #,
         call    __printf_chk@PLT        #
```

Actually,  in 2021, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) (and complicates matter). Look into [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/).

Comment: Nops, 97 and 65 are their respective decimal values.